# Is it possible to express `stuff.map {|x| puts x}` more succinctly?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, block

I would like to use some sort of shorthand to express the following:

```
stuff.map {|x| puts x}
```

to something like this:

```
stuff.map {puts}
```

I cannot figure out the syntax. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: When you say "express something more succinctly", it's a clue that this should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Read [the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) for that site, especially "I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?"

Comment: Since no-one mentioned it - using `map` is completely redundant here, use `each`

Comment: map is better for the console because it returns null.  each will return the object which clutters the console output

Comment: @rsoni If `Enumerable#map` returned nil we'd be in all sorts of trouble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have an array, you could just write

```
puts stuff
```

However, in general, you can add a method to String or Object that can then be passed directly to an `Enumerable.` Since `Symbol` has a `to_proc` method, you can have that method called without needing a block.

```
class Object; def myputs; puts self; nil; end; end

stuff.each &:myputs # or, even better, ...

stuff.myputs
```

Comment: Ahh, good point, since `#puts` no doubt calls `#to_s` on its argument.

Answer (score 6):

First off: it doesn't make sense to use `map` here, since you are not doing a mapping operation, but a simple side-effecting iteration. That's *exactly* what `each` is for. Using `map` is only confusing to future maintainers (including yourself).

`each` and `map` take a block. You can use the unary prefix `&` operator to turn any object that responds to `to_proc` into a block. Thankfully, `Method`s *do* respond to `to_proc`, so you can pass the method you want to call directly:

```
stuff.each(&method(:puts))
```

However, if `stuff` is an `Array`, there is an even easier way, because `puts` special-cases `Array`s to do exactly what you are doing. So, your code is 100% equivalent to just

```
puts stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you were implying `map(&:method)` syntax but in the `puts`' case it's impossible.

Under the hood, Ruby calls `to_proc` on the symbol. The body of this method is:

```
def to_proc
  proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
end
```

In your case the obj is `stuff` and self is `puts`.

As you can understand, `stuff` doesn't respond to the `puts` method so then you can't use symbol construction in the current expression.

Answer (score 2):

#### You Need a Receiver

The block format of [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) returns an array, so you still need a receiver (such as Kernel, using [Kernel#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)) to send each element to standard output. You could do something like this:

```
puts [1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s)
```

but that certainly doesn't make things shorter or more clear. Perhaps you should revisit what it is that you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I use that often to read things more clearly in the console, so I just wanted a shorter version since I type it a lot. I know in javascript this can be done more concisely, just wanted to try to do it in ruby the same

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s)` will return `["1", "2", "3"]` on the REPL, which sounds like what you want. However, it won't send it directly to standard output as with `puts`--it just looks that way because IRB/Pry will show return values by default as part of the read-eval-print loop.

Answer (score 2):

Though its already closed, I suggest:

```
stuff.map(&Kernel.method(:puts))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
a.map(& puts)
```

returns an enumerator. You could also do something like:

```
puts a.map(&:to_s)
```

to print out each element.

Comment: This will return an array of strings. It won't send the output anywhere.